# Does Android have IsHitTestVisible like WPF?

Tags: android, wpf

Does Android have `IsHitTestVisible` (The property which make elements not hittable by mouse or touch) like WPF?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @kaushik The property which make elements not hittable by mouse or touch

Comment: don't set any `OnClickListener` or `OnTouchListener` on that view

Comment: I can't because I want process all TouchEvents at the ViewGroup level.

Comment: please describe what u want briefly in question with screenshot if possible